# Querying fields in a schemaless Solr throws "undefined field" error

Tags: solr

We are running Solr in schemaless mode. When querying the index for certain fields with `myfield:value` syntax, I get an `"undefined field <myfield>"` error if no document containing that field has been indexed yet.

This kind of defeats the purpose of schemaless mode. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want first premise that Solr schemaless mode is not for production use, it is for prototyping a new web application, or to load a bulk of data easily and than analyse them, but after, when you collection is stable, should be disabled.

You could use the [Solr Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schema-api.html), before make any query and double check if the field you're using exists really.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema/fields
```

**UPDATE: explained downsides of Solr Schemaless mode and added a suggestion**

When Schemaless mode is active (`update.autoCreateFields` is set `true`):

```xml
<updateRequestProcessorChain 
   name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema"
   default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
   processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
```

you're asking Solr to guess the type for each new field you're indexing. So, what happens when Solr is unfortunately wrong? You don't have other way that manually modify the schema, which will almost certainly require a full reindex.

Certainly I don't want the production schema change because, in some unknown way, new fields has arrived during an update.

If you want use a solution where fields are added dynamically, I suggest to use dynamic fields. So you'll have two benefits:

1. you decide the fieldType only when add new fields
2. when you know the fieldType, query like `myfield_str:value` does not throw any exception, even if the field doesn't exist.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. Whats the downside of schemaless Solr in production?

Comment: I've updated my answer trying to explain downsides of schemaless Solr in production.